# Many to many relationships in Yii2

Tags: yii2, many-to-many

I am trying to create a many to many relationship between a profile and several fields within that profile including languages and specialities. I have looked at several implementations and understand that there are several extensions, but I am required to minimise usage of extensions.

I have created the proper migration...this is a skeleton and the user table is purely for logins and OAuth...so keys can be ignored. As you can see in my controller I don't really know the way forward at this point. My language model is for all intensive purposes static from this controller(It is controlled by an admin backend).  What is working? If I make a couple modifications to the below code then the checkboxlist will display with the proper checked items that I manually added to the lookup table. Trying to modify the lookup table from code, I have been unable to do unless I populate the $languageModel with a findOne(knownPK), however that is not usable, because multiple checkboxes can be selected resulting in an array and the link command requires ActiveRecordInterface which is singular. Ideally I would like to simply use

```
     $languageModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post(),$trainerModel->formName());
```

but that isn't working.

Additionally, is there a mechanism within the framework to remove lookups or is that done manually. Any help or insight would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

```
  public function safeUp()
 {
     $this->createTable('student', [
        'id'                 => $this->primaryKey(),
        'user_id'            => $this->integer()->notNull(),
    ]);

     $this->createTable('language', [
        'id'                 => $this->primaryKey(),
        'language' => $this->string(63),
    ]);

    $this->createTable('student_language',[
        'id'                 => $this->primaryKey(),
        'language_id' => $this->integer(),
        'student_id'  => $this->integer()
    ]);

      $this->addForeignKey('fk-student-language-language', 'student_language', 'language_id', 'language', 'id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE');
      $this->addForeignKey('fk-student-language-student', 'student_language', 'student_id', 'student', 'id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE');
      $this->addForeignKey('fk-student-user-user_id', 'student', 'user_id', 'user', 'id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE');
   }
```

My student Active Record

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getstudentLanguages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(studentLanguage::className(), ['student_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getLanguages(){
    return $this->hasMany(Language::className(),['id'=>'language_id'])->viaTable('student_language',['student_id'=>'id']);
}
```

My Language Model

```
 /**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getstudentLanguages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(studentLanguage::className(), ['language_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getLanguages(){
    return $this->hasMany(student::className(),['id'=>'student_id'])->viaTable('student_language',['language_id'=>'id']);
}
```

My Controller

```
 public function actionProfile()
{
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('This page requires you to be logged in');
    } else {
        $user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->getId();
        $studentModel = $this->findstudentModelByUserId($user_id);
        if (is_null($studentModel)) {
            $studentModel = new student();
            $studentModel->setAttribute('user_id', $user_id);
            $studentModel->save();
        }

    $languageModel = ??????????????????


        $studentModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $studentModel->save() && $studentModel->link('languages',$languageModel);

    }

    return $this->render('profile', ['model' => $studentModel]);
}
```

My View

```
   <?= $form->field($model, 'languages')->checkboxList(\common\models\Language::find()->select(
                        ['language', 'id'])->indexBy('id')->column(),      ['prompt' => 'select Language']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution at this point, however I am interested to hear improvements. 
**Note:** There is no error checking etc...just functional code.

I added this to the student activerecord class

```
   public function linkMultiple( $name,Array $models){

    studentLanguage::deleteAll(['student_id' =>$this->id]);

    foreach($models as $model){
        $this->link($name, $model);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Modified my Controller action to the following

```
   public function actionProfile()
{
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('This page requires you to be logged in');
    } else {
        $user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->getId();
        $studentModel = $this->findstudentModelByUserId($user_id);
        if (is_null($studentModel)) {
            $studentModel = new student();
            $studentModel->setAttribute('user_id', $user_id);
            $studentModel->save();
        }

        $languages = Yii::$app->request->post('student')['languages'];
        $languageModels = Language::findAll($languages);

        $studentModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $studentModel->save() && $studentModel->linkMultiple('languages',$languageModels);

    }

    return $this->render('profile', ['model' => $studentModel]);
}
```